# click on td doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I have tried so far

```
$('#new-item').click(function(){alert('Hi');});
$('tr #new-item').click(function(){alert('Hi');});
$('.create-list #new-item').click(function(){alert('Hi');});
$('.create-list table tbody tr #new-item').click(function(){alert('Hi');});
$('.create-list table').on('click','#new-item',function(){alert('hi')});
$('.create-list table').on('click','tr #new-item',function(){alert('hi')});
```

and etc. I tried also like `.create-list>table>tbody>tr>td` but also didn't work.
With this DOM

```
<div class='create-list'><table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="new-item">click me</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table></div>
```

I know this was asked before but I can't get this to work, It should alert something when `new-item` is clicked. I searched for solutions, but all didn't work. Other jquery functions are working well inside of the script file so no worrying about jquery links etc.

fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/oj6jbk0a/6/

Comment: I think we need more information here. Like whether create-list exists all the time or not (or if it even exists at some point).

Comment: What about `$('#new-item').onclick = function(){alert('Hi')};`

Comment: Try to use the webdevelopment tools of your browser - it might be that some error disables the complete functionality, it might be that you can't hit the element because of some CSS weirdness.

Comment: This works just fine - can you post your site or recreate the problem? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEYdww

Comment: Css isn't the problem iguess I didn't style the table, console is also not showing anything :( @axel.michel

Comment: @zurfyx the .create-list is just a container/ wrapper on the table

Comment: @variableUnknown Bit crazy, but try with this: `$(document).on('click', '#new-item', function() { alert('..') })`

Comment: @zurfyx nope also didn't work :(

Comment: @variableUnknown if you can, post your code on jsfiddle, edit your initial question, and we'll look it up

Comment: Hmm okey first I want to mention something what I orginally was something I personally thought I wouldn't matter but the tables parent is a form and inside other table rows there are some inputs. I used the table to  give a structure. Just to mention I also tried $('form table #new-item') and $('form').on('click', '#new-item'...etc.);

Comment: @variableUnknown that doesn't matter as long as the `form table #new-item` order is correct and `#new-item` is unique across the whole page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your working fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/oj6jbk0a/8/)

Your problems:

- Always validate your HTML, as it can generate impossible-to-find errors.
- Every `id` must be unique in a page.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. It seems because your js code gets run before DOM elements are placed on the page.

Try following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#new-item').click(function(){alert('Hi');});
})
```

Then it should be working.

If your `td` element is created by some js code on some time much after the document is ready, then just put the code after `td` generation code.

## 2. You might have several elements with the same id in the document.

If you have several elements in the page with the same id, jQuery just returns only first element no matter how many elements you have.

Check the example to see how jQuery works when several elements are there with the same ID value:

```js
$('#new-item').html('Hello');
```

```css
#new-item {
  min-height: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new-item"></div>
<div id="new-item"></div>
<div id="new-item"></div>
```

## 3. You might have jQuery conflicted

In this case you will notice error in the console.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already have it in a document ready function

Comment: @variableUnknown Then make sure there is only 1 element with the given id new-item in the page

Comment: Yep It's the only element given the id new-item

Comment: @variableUnknown did you check by view source code? if you tried $('#new-item').length it will return 1 no matter how many elements you have with the ID value.